# Highlighted Content only showing Documents original Title, doesn't change if Title is updated

Tags: sharepoint-online, highlighted-content-web-part

I have a Highlighted Content web-part embedded on my Modern SharePoint Online page, and have it configured to show files from a document library.

The problem I have is: if I modify the Title of a document directly in the document library - the new Title does not get updated in the Highlighed Content web-part.  It continues to show the old Title, regardless of how much time passes (days, months, etc).  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with Microsoft Support, and they suggested modifying the mapping for the 'Title' Managed Property in our site, and moving "Office:2" to the top:

1. Go to 'Site Settings', and click 'Search Schema'.
2. Search for "Title", and then right-click/edit the Managed Property for 'Title'
3. Scroll down to 'Mappings to crawled properties' and move 'Office:2' to the top of the list, and then save the change.
4. Go to the affetced document library settings, click 'Advanced Settings' > click 'Reindex Document Library'.

I can confirm this resolved our issue, and the highlighted content now displays the Title field for all documents accurately.

Answer (score 1):

We noticed the same behaviour yesterday. It's working for PDF just not Word Documents.

The only way I could get the title to change was to upload the document with a new filename but obviously this is not a solution.

James

Comment: You might be on to something there with the Word documents - after further testing, it seems the Title is only correctly shown for other filetypes (including Excel, for example).  However, Word documents seem to show the first line of the files *contents*, and not the title or file name.  I'll have to do further testing, and may end up needing to raise with Microsoft support...

Comment: Yes I hope they fix it soon. Please keep us informed of how you get on.

Comment: We managed to resolve it with Microsoft's guidance, see my self-accepted answer on this page :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing title or name column? They are different columns and per my knowledge the Highlight content web part shall display document name column as the file name.